# Gitlab remote: fatal: write error: No space left on device

Tags: git, gitlab, ubuntu-20.04

I get the following error when I do `git push -f origin master`

```
warning: redirecting to https://gitlab.iit.it/muhammad.mehdi/memex-app.git/
Enumerating objects: 1048, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1048/1048), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (618/618), done.
remote: fatal: write error: No space left on device
```

I did `df -h` and I get the following

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.8M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6  227G  109G  107G  51% /
tmpfs           7.7G  148M  7.5G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      9.2M  9.2M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop3       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop5      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/10908
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop6       46M   46M     0 100% /snap/dotnet-runtime-50/11
/dev/loop8       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/904
/dev/loop7       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop9      218M  218M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop10     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop0      926M  926M     0 100% /snap/android-studio/101
/dev/loop11      63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop12      16M   16M     0 100% /snap/kolourpaint/56
/dev/loop13     163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop15      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11402
/dev/loop14     291M  291M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4
/dev/loop16      52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop17     111M  111M     0 100% /snap/xournalpp/48
/dev/loop18     200M  200M     0 100% /snap/code/60
/dev/loop19     111M  111M     0 100% /snap/xournalpp/42
/dev/loop20      62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/975
/dev/loop21      51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/481
/dev/loop22     132M  132M     0 100% /snap/dotnet-sdk/116
/dev/loop23     324M  324M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14
/dev/loop24     113M  113M     0 100% /snap/kolourpaint/59
/dev/loop25     426M  426M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/232
/dev/loop26      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11107
/dev/loop27     426M  426M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/233
/dev/nvme0n1p1   96M   53M   44M  55% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   20K  1.6G   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs           1.6G   68K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/loop28     100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/10958
/dev/loop2      1.1G  1.1G     0 100% /snap/root-framework/130
```

I have 114 GB of free disk space:

[image: 1]

How do I solve this issue? I have deleted so much stuff from my home folder and the picture clearly says I have free space. Then what's the problem?

Comment: It sounds to me like where the problem of disk space exists is on the remote Git server.  Is that a server of yours (run by your company rather than by GitLab)?  If so, then it makes more sense that it might be out of disk space on whatever partition the Git repos are being stored on.

Comment: To whomever voted to close this question...I disagree with your reason for doing so.  This is a question about a tool most often used to develop software.  That makes this on-topic for S.O., at least from the standpoint of the general topic being discussed.

Comment: So it is a problem on the gitlab website where I am trying to push files and not on my own laptop right? Because I have been going crazy for the past hour deleting tons of stuff to free up disk space. I now have 115 GB of free disk space in my home folder

Comment: Yes, I think that's what is going on here.  Again...can you tell me something about the Git server you are connecting to?  Does it make any sense that it might be having a disk space problem?

Comment: I am committing files to a repository I setup on Gitlab. It is private and can only be accessed by me and another guy in my company at the moment.

Comment: Can you look at whatever environment Gitlab is running in and see if disk space is a problem there?  I'd wager that there is a disk space issue there.

Comment: I don't understand this? What should I do? I am on Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and I have opened the gitlab repository on chrome.

Comment: Where is Gitlab actually running?  On your laptop or somewhere else?  I assume it's running somewhere else, or your URL would start with `\https://localhost...`

Comment: This is the url where my repository is hosted: https://gitlab.iit.it/muhammad.mehdi/memex

I run git from my terminal in Ubuntu on my personal company laptop

Comment: I get that...but hosted by who?

Comment: what do you mean hosted? I created the repository on gitlab and it is obviously hosted on gitlab. I only started using gitlab a month ago, so I don't have the vocabulary to understand what you're asking

Comment: I was given access to gitlab by my company. So, the account was provided by them

Comment: `https://gitlab.iit.it/muhammad.mehdi/memex-app.git/` is the address of an external Git repository hosted on some system other than your laptop.  When you do `git push -f origin master`, your system is sending data to this external system so that it will update its copy of the repository you are working on so that it contains the same code as your local copy.  For this to work, there is some system running a program that makes that remote Git repository available to you.  If I'm right, whatever system is running that remote Git repository software is out of disk space.

Comment: Is there a way to check this limit on gitlab using my account there?

Comment: I don't know much about Gitlab, so I don't know what it might offer beyond standard Git.  Git itself has no such function.  The only solution might be to get in contact with whomever is responsible for hosting that server.  Is there an IT person or department in your company that you can ask about this problem?  It still isn't clear to me if your company is hosting this server or if it is a third party service.  Do you recognize the domain `iit.it` as being associated with your company?  If you do, then someone in your company has to know about this.

Comment: That's actually what I am doing right now. Thank you for the help, at least I know now it is not a problem on my end.

Comment: I wouldn't stake my life on it not being on your end, but the error message seems somewhat clear to me, and if you're sure your laptop has plenty of disk space, then it only makes sense that the server is full.  BTW, I just put `iit.it` into my browser.  You work for Istituto Italiano Di Technologia?  If so, then someone at your company has to know how to help you with this.

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with your IT people?

Comment: Well I sent them the email on the night of Easter Monday and today is Tuesday. Hopefully, they will get back to me soon.

Comment: I cleaned up snap packages by removing unused ones: sudo snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' | while read snapname revision; do sudo snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"; done

Answer (score 2):

The "remote:" message here means that the message you're seeing came from the remote side.  In this case, the remote side (that is, the Git server) said, “fatal: write error: No space left on device”.

Therefore, the most likely thing to conclude here is that your Git server is out of space.  You should contact the party responsible for maintaining that server and ask them to fix the problem.  There wouldn't be anything that you could do to fix the problem unless you administer the server.

Comment: If you read my discourse with i_am_juan, you saw that I've been saying the same thing.  @carnicer's answer sounded so sure of itself that it had me scrambling to make sure I had not misdiagnosed the issue.  Thanks for coming along and confirming what I've been telling the OP.

Comment: I did, and I would have upvoted your answer had it not been deleted.

Comment: We can still trade upvotes :) - I guess I was quite a wimp for pulling back my answer because someone else was sounding so sure of themselves and mentioning something (snaps) that I had never heard of before (I guess it's an Ubuntu thing...I'm a RH/Centos guy).

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `git push -f origin master` command is to update a remote repository running somewhere other than your own laptop so that its copy of the repository you are working will contain the changes you've made to that repository.  The existence of this remote repository is what allows collaboration by multiple programmers on a single set of source code.

That error message is telling you that the remote server that you are attempting to push (copy, update) your code to is out of disk space on whatever disk volume it is storing the Git repositories that it manages.

Since `iit.it` looks to me like a company that would not be in the business of hosting Git repositories for other businesses, I assume that this remote Git repository is either being hosted by your company or is being hosted by someone else solely for use by your company.  Therefore, what you need to do is reach out to the IT support people at your company to find out what is going on here.  It is likely that something needs to be done to free up or add disk space to the server(s) running the remote Git repository.

Comment: @i_am_juan - Greetings.  I am wondering if my answer to your question was helpful.  Did it answer your question?  If so, I encourage you to accept it as the correct answer via the checkmark button.  Note that you get points for accepting an answer.

Answer (score -3):

Your `/snap` partition is 100% full. We do not know the details of your system configuration, but it is highly likely that the system is not even capable to perform the required operations in order to process the push command.

Try another operation such as a `fetch`. If the fetch operation also fails for the same reason, it is most likely the lack of local disk space.

Then you can also delete stuff in `/snap`. If you can, and it works, then that's it.

Can you do `git remote -v` to make sure you are working against a remote server?

Comment: I do this: 
git remote -v

And then I get this:
    origin https://gitlab.iit.it/muhammad.mehdi/memex.git (fetch)
    origin https://gitlab.iit.it/muhammad.mehdi/memex.git (push)

What does this mean?

Comment: I also did:
`git fetch https://gitlab.iit.it/muhammad.mehdi/memex`

And then I get this:
`warning: redirecting to https://gitlab.iit.it/muhammad.mehdi/memex.git/
From https://gitlab.iit.it/muhammad.mehdi/memex
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: I've never heard of a `/snap` partition.  What is that?  Can you explain it?  I googled for that specific error message, and found two threads that involved IT departments apologizing for having issues with their servers.  What makes you so sure it's local?

Comment: I've googled to ask the enlightened big G what "/snap" is.  It seems to be a place that the package manager named "snap" stores the packages it installs.  Is that right?  If it is, I don't see how that could have anything to do with Git not having the space that it needs.  I'm not yet buying that this is local.

Comment: I just found this quote: "Welcome to AskUbuntu! Snap apps are sandboxed so they always show 100% used. Their settings and data are actually stored in your home user folder."  This sounds like a red herring to me.

Comment: You can clean snap packages by removing unused ones:
sudo snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' | while read snapname revision; do sudo snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"; done